# what should be the datatype of field to store arrays

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to store an array (say for example 20*20) in ms sql server,then what should be the datatype of the same?
The table is test and fields are ID,focus,name.
I want to store arrays in focus field.
Please tell me how to do that

Comment: SQL has two datatypes *designed* for holding multiple values - tables and xml.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever where can i find an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't.

You should create a separate table (eg: testfocus) with a row for each element of your array, and a foreign key to your test table.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: @VivekSaurav If you can give an example of the contents of your array, yes.